# What are some best practices / conventions / guidelines for ASP.NET or C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

Long ago I read a great book on C# and Visual Basic best practices:

*Practical Guidelines and Best Practices for Microsoft Visual Basic and Visual C# Developers*
by Francesco Balena, Giuseppe Dimauro

[image]
<sub>(source: [dotnet2themax.com](http://www.dotnet2themax.com/Books/PracticalGuidelines_Cover.gif))</sub>

This book was very helpful to me in its time, which dates back to ASP.NET 1.1.  Please list some current best practices for ASP.NET, C#, and Visual Basic.  And if you've read the book, what are some best practices or guidelines within it that you feel have been outdated?

Comment: i think this question is far to general and doesn't have a right answer.

Comment: Image you've posted isn't shown

Answer (score 4):

For C# and .Net in general I'd highly recommend picking up Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Adams' book "[Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613)". That book along with running my code against FxCop and the ReSharper Code Analysis has really helped me keep my code clean and lean

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to list all good practices at once.  But here is a starting list.

- Always start developing your pages by disabling state management features like the view state and session.  Enable them only if they are absolutely necessary.
- Know the ASP.Net page life cycle.
- Don't mix up html markup with code and javascript.
- Embed web resources like images and java script files in a .Net assembly.

Answer (score 1):

The [Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613) by Krzysztof Cwalina and Brad Adams is probably the best resource out there.  While the book emphasizes of reusable libraries you can easily tailor the guidance to standards projects.

[Brad Adams](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/default.aspx) (one of the authors of the book), also blogs about many of the rules frequently.

C# and VB coding Standards Reference documents

For coding style, look at Clint Edmonson's [C# and VB coding Standards Reference Documents](http://www.notsotrivial.net/blog/post/2008/12/Holiday-Goodie-Bag-Free-C-and-VB-Coding-Standards-Reference-Documents.aspx).

Two good resoruces for ASP.NET specific guidance is the [MSDN Security Guidelines: ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998258.aspx) and the [ASP.NET Coding Standards](http://www.education.vic.gov.au/devreskit/appdev/Standards/ASP/aspnet-standards-summary.htm) published by the Victoria, Australia's Department of Eduction and Early Childhood Development.

Finally, SSW (another group in Australia) has a great section called [SSW Rules to Better...](http://www.ssw.com.au/ssw/standards/Default.aspx) which has all kinds of rules for different development activities.